# Probability of a number randomly chosen out of given numbers

Tags: probability, binomial-coefficients

**Three numbers are chosen at random without replacement from {1, 2, 3, ...,
10}. What is the probability that the minimum of the chosen number is 3, or their
maximum is 7?**

**Approach 1:**
Let A and B denote the following events
A:minimum of the chosen number is 3
B: maximum of the chosen number is 7
We have,
P(A)=P(choosing 3 and two other numbers from 4 to 10)=${{7\choose2}\over{10\choose3}}={(7*6)\over2}*{3*2\over10*9*8}={7\over40}$
P(B)=P(choosing 7 and two other numbers from 1 to 6)=${{6\choose2}\over{10\choose3}}={6*5\over2}*{3*2\over10*9*8}={1\over8}$
P(A∩B)=P(Choosing 3 and 7 and one other number from 4 to 6)$={3\over{10\choose3}}={3*3*2\over10*9*8}={1\over40}$
Now P(A∪B)=P(A)+P(B)−P(A∩B)
$={7\over40}+{1\over8}-{1\over40}={11\over40}$
**Approach 2:**
Chance of a number being drawn out of the given 10 numbers is equiprobable. Hence
P(any one number drawn )=${1\over10}$

P(A)=${7\choose2}{1\over10}*{7\over9}*{6\over8}=21*{42\over720}={14*7\over80}={98\over80}$ which is wrong as it is above 1.
Here, ${1\over10}$ is the probability of getting 3 and ${7\over9}*{6\over8}$ is the probability of getting two number above 3 which can be chosen in ${7\choose2}$ ways.

**Why I cannot find the P(A) like this ?
Please tell me what is wrong in approach 2 **

Comment: Hard to follow what you wrote for the second approach.  First approach looks fine.

Comment: In the second approach, I tried to solve the question with Probability multiplication rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach 2 has three errors.  First, you are double multiplying by $7 \choose 2$, once when you use the binomial and once in the numerators of $\frac 79$ and $\frac 68$.  When you use $\frac 79$ and $\frac 68$ you are already choosing the numbers.  You have a factor $2$ when you use $\frac 79$ and $\frac 68$ (note $7 \cdot 6=2{7 \choose 2})$ because there are two orders to select each pair and you count them both.  Finally, you only count cases where $3$ is the first number selected.

Comment: Hi could you please explain the last sentence? Doesn’t (3,5,6) and (5,6,3) mean the same in this context?

Comment: @insipidintegrator: yes and that is what I am complaining about.  The first factor is $\frac 1{10}$, which is the chance of choosing $3$.  The calculation does not try to include the chance of $(5,6,3)$ as I understand it.

Comment: @RossMillikan I just got it . Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

The correct working for Approach $2$, (general multiplication rule) using your notation:

$P(A)=P$(choosing $3$ and two other numbers from $4-10)= \frac3{10}\frac7{9}\frac68={7\over40}$

$P(B)=P$(choosing $7$ and two other numbers from $1-6)=\frac3{10}\frac69\frac58 ={1\over8}$

$P(A\cap B)=P$(Choosing $3$ and $7$ and one other number from $4-6) = \frac3{10}\frac39\frac28 ={1\over40}$

The figures now tally, and you can proceed further as before